# Selenium webdriver how to do file upload with ng-click="upload('files')"

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, selenium

I'm trying to see if this is possible - to automate a file upload when the HTML code is NOT an

```
< input type='file' >
```

but rather a link

```
<a ng-click="upload('files')"> File Upload </a>
```

When this link is clicked, it automatically opens a file selector to choose which file you want to upload.
The problem is, it does not contain an INPUT type='file' element which I could locate and then use webdriver.send_keys('/Users/myname/testfile.txt').

How can I go about trying to get selenium webdriver to handle this file upload?

Any help to direct me to a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your application seems like an angularjs one. You are not using protractor, right?

Comment: I am afraid the solution would depend on `upload()` function implementation. Can you provide it? Thanks.

Comment: Also a public demo of the upload link like this would help to provide a reliable solution.

Comment: Yes, additionaly it looks like a file upload will appear after clicking on the link in source code. That's why we need to know what will happen after clicking :)

Comment: It was actually making a call to a browser plugin, that's why I couldn't find the element. For this scenario, I think that an outside executable such as AutoIT is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time that i needed this WebDriver couldn't interact with dialogs cause dialogs are the domain of the operating system and not the webpage.

One option would be to skip the file dialog entirely and issue a POST/GET/PUT, but this requires more advanced knowledge of the website as well as understanding of how to construct a request.

What i did in that ocation was to create an auxiliar program executable for dealing with the dialog, so i called it in the middle of the Selenium script, just after generating the dialog.

*Here you have a sample of the last approach using Java & AutoIT: http://www.automationtesting.co.in/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html*

Comment: I saw autoIT when I was googling for solutions, but it seems just used for windows. Is there something similar for Mac or Linux?

Comment: In the same web there is a sample using AppleScript for Mac: http://www.automationtesting.co.in/2009/08/selenium-handling-dialog-box-in-mac.html

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

See this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145054/using-selenium-iwebdriver-to-test-an-activex-control-possible?noredirect=1#comment37272381_24145054). I had this question as well, and AutoIt was the answer to uploading a file when you don't have an input option in HTML.

Here is a link to [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). They have some tutorials to get you started.